# SimpleXML - I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a small application that will simply read an RSS feed and then layout the info on the page.

All the instructions I find make this seem simplistic but for some reason it just isn't working. I have the following

```
include_once(ABSPATH.WPINC.'/rss.php');
$feed = file_get_contents('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/rss.xml?edition=int');
$items = simplexml_load_file($feed);
```

That's it, it then breaks on the third line with the following error

```
Error: [2] simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <?xm
The rest of the XML file is shown.
```

I have turned on allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include in my settings but still nothing.
I've tried multiple feeds that all end up with the same result?

I'm going mad here

Comment: `simplexml_load_file()` expects the filename! Use [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) for already loaded data

Comment: So simple and yet so effective.. thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`simplexml_load_file()` interprets an **XML file** (either a file on your  disk or a URL)  into an object. What you have in `$feed` is a string.

You have two options:

- Use `file_get_contents()` to get the XML feed as a string, and use e [`simplexml_load_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php):

  ```
   $feed = file_get_contents('...');
   $items = simplexml_load_string($feed);
  ```
- Load the XML feed directly using [`simplexml_load_file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php):

  ```
   $items = simplexml_load_file('...');
  ```

Comment: A note about using file_get_contents() . I encountered the same error (I/O warning : failed to load external entity) and discovered that it was caused by my PHP config. Check upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in php.ini and make sure they are at least as large as the file you are attempting to parse.

Answer (score 4):

You can also load the content with cURL, if file_get_contents insn't enabled on your server.

Example:

```
$ch = curl_init();  

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/rss.xml?edition=int");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$items = simplexml_load_string($output);
```

Answer (score 2):

this also works:

```
$url = "http://www.some-url";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xmlresponse = curl_exec($ch);
$xml=simplexml_load_string($xmlresponse);
```

then I just run a forloop to grab the stuff from the nodes.

like this:`

```
for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
$title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
$link = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
$desc = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
$html .="<div><h3>$title</h3>$link<br />$desc</div><hr>";
}
echo $html;
```

***note that your node names will differ, obviously..and your HTML might be structured differently...also your loop might be set to higher or lower amount of results.

Answer (score -1):

```
$url = 'http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/materia/tramitando';
$xml = file_get_contents("xml->{$url}");
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Comment: Júnior, ché, add some explanation to your answer so we can upvote it :)